# Oracle Enterprise Manager 11g Database Control - Agent Unreachable

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, oracle-enterprise-manager

Single instance DB. I can login to Oracle Enterprise Manger (OEM). However,  on the Home Page it says:

> ```
> Status - Agent Unreachable
> ```

Most tasks such as checking RMAN status, adding datafiles, etc. can still be done through the OEM. I do not know how ***Agent Unreachable*** impacts the OEM in this case (DB Control)

I checked status of the agent from `$ORACLE_HOME/bin/emctl status agent`, it showed:

> ```
> The Agent is not Running
> ```

So, I want to start the agent, but running the command `$ORACLE_HOME/bin/emctl start agent` is not working. The command is not available.

In Oracle docs, it is mentioned that the command `emctl start agent` should be executed from `AGENT_HOME/bin`. However, I do not know the `AGENT_HOME` path.

How can I start the OEM Agent or figure out what the underlying issue is?

Comment: What do(es) the log file(s) say?

Comment: Dear Colin,  I need to execute the "emctl start agent" command to effectively check the log files. At the moment, I am not being able to start the agent.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have separate Oracle Homes for your Database and Grid Infrastructure (which was *new* to 11gR2, IIRC)?

If so, then the Agent probably runs from the *Grid Infrastructure's* Oracle Home.

Annoyingly, the bin directory in *both* Oracle Homes contains a program called **emctl** but only *one* of them will work as you expect!

If in doubt use the Linux **find** command to locate anything called emctl ...

```
find ???  -type f  -name emctl  -ls
```

I'd suggest, once you've found it, you add the Agent's "Oracle Home" into /etc/oratab under its own name, to make it easier to find it *next* time.